# How to sort an array by boolean values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
array(
  array('foo' => true),
  array('foo' => false),
  array('foo' => true),
  array('foo' => true),
  array('foo' => false)
)
```

Is there a simple way to bring all the arrays where `foo == true` to the top?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php might be the droid you are looking for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the [`uasort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) function to order your array:

```
$arr = array(
    array('foo' => true),
    array('foo' => false),
    array('foo' => true),
    array('foo' => true),
    array('foo' => false)
);

function sortit($a, $b) {
    if($a['foo'] === $b['foo']) {
        return 0;
    }

    return $a['foo'] > $b['foo'] ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($arr, 'sortit');
```

Answer (score 1):

[`rsort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) will actually do that for you:

```
<?php

$a = array(
  array('foo' => true),
  array('foo' => false),
  array('foo' => true),
  array('foo' => true),
  array('foo' => false)
);

rsort($a);

var_dump($a);
```

Yields:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'foo' => boolean true
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'foo' => boolean true
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'foo' => boolean true
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'foo' => boolean false
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
      'foo' => boolean false
```

Hope this helps!